# Show that {$x \in I | f(x) = g(x)$} is closed using the Global Continuity Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing

Let $I = [a, b]$ and let $f, g : I \to R$ be continuous functions on I. Show that {$x \in I | f(x) = g(x)$} is closed using the Global Continuity Theorem.

My classmate and I have been struggling with this for two days now. I've gotten that f(x)=g(x) is bounded by the Boundedness Thm- however, boundedness does not imply closedness and I'm not sure what to do next. The Global Continuity Theorem states that if a set is closed its inverse image is closed- how do I figure out what the inverse image is? Would it be f(x)-g(x)?

Comment: Hint: write the set in terms of the function $h=f-g$. Note that whatever is your global continuity theorem it cannot say what you wrote (since it is false).

Comment: I forgot the word "if". And okay, then h=0 for all x. How do I prove that's the inverse?

Comment: Perhaps you want then to add continuity.

Comment: Yes, h(x) is continuous because the subtraction of two continuous functions is still continous

Comment: So you are all set. Now just think a bit more.